# How can I exclude a row from a formula based on a value of one cell in it in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a spreadsheet for a project that involves listing five ingredients for a recipe, along with a number value of how many of that ingredient is needed. I am then using functions in Google Sheets to automatically create a list of all unique ingredients and how many there are across all rows, broadly seen here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnRLk.png)

For the "Ingredient List" I am using the code:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(E4:E, G4:G, I4:I, K4:K, M4:M), FLATTEN(E4:E, G4:G, I4:I, K4:K, M4:M)<>"")))
```

And for the "#" column to the right of it I am using the code:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($F$4:$F,O4=$E$4:$E)))+IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($H$4:$H,O4=$G$4:$G)))+IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($J$4:$J,O4=$I$4:$I)))+IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($L$4:$L,O4=$K$4:$K)))+IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($N$4:$N,O4=$M$4:$M)))
```

What I would like to do is to make so that if the value in column D ("Obtained?") is "Yes", then the entire row (E-N) is excluded from the two lists in columns O and P, but I do not want anything to be deleted. This would allow me to depopulate the "Ingredient List" as additional rows are marked "Yes", theoretically until a point where it is empty.

Is this something I can plausibly do using the tools within Google Sheets, and if so, how? Thank you!

I've tried some variations of "If" or "Ifs", but I need it to check every cell in one column from one cell (O4 and P4).

UPDATE 2/22/23: The below solution worked, but seems to have broken as of this date for unknown reasons. I am once again looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this in `Cell O4`. you may need to clear the exsiting formula(s) in `columns O & P` to let this formula freely expand.

```
=let(a,filter(E4:N,D4:D="No"),b,tocol(choosecols(a,1,3,5,7,9),1),c,tocol(choosecols(a,2,4,6,8,10),1),byrow(unique(b),lambda(z,{z,sum(filter(c,b=z))})))
```

[image]

***Updated formula***:

```
=let(
    a,filter(E4:N,D4:D="No"),
    b,flatten(filter(a,mod(column(E4:N),2)<>0)),
    c,flatten(filter(a,mod(column(E4:N),2)=0)),
query({b,c},"Select Col1, sum(Col2) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I think the one part of this I forget to mention is that some ingredient columns may be empty, depending on the individual row. Some may use all 5 columns but others may only use 2 or 3. How might I adjust for a situation like this, if at all?

Comment: the formula will work just fine if ingredient+associated_quantity are blank in row(s) but again this will not work if ingredient name is entered and no quantity is entered to its immediate right. Is it the later scenario you were referring to?

Comment: Hi, I don't think if this will ever get seen, but it appears this formula has stopped working?  I am getting a "result should be a single column" error. It was working fine before today. Thank you!

Comment: google has [rolled back](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en&msgid=202965915) some of those new functions used in the formula earlier; so the issue. added updated answer for you to check out. cool

Comment: Thank you very much. That link seems to suggest they intend to bring it back somewhat soon, at the very least. This works well as you have it, however I've actually since added one additional column left (a new "A" column), which seems to break your new code even if I adjust the old D4:D to E4:E and E4:N to F4:O. Deleting that new "A" column seems to cause it to work as intended. Would you mind helping me understand why changing those ranges alone wouldn't fix the issue? Thank you very, very much.

Comment: sorry hard to pinpoint without having a look at the sheet. it could be any number of things that could be causing this amiss.

Comment: The error being generated is "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC", if that's any help. It works if I move everything back over one column to the values you have written out, so I know the data in the ingredients columns isn't at fault, but I'd like to have that additional column if at all possible. Short of that, I may wait out the reimplementation of those suspended functions.

Comment: the error could mean some text column is part of the `sum` calculation within `query` part